# Android Studio Render problem: font does not exist (or is not a file)

Tags: android, android-studio

On Android Studio Dolphin 2021.3.1 SDK 33, out of the blue, I've encountered a render problem error with any web font: "File app/src/main/res/font/rubik_bold.xml does not exist (or is not a file)".

Refreshing the layout doesn't help. I've tried clean and rebuild, Gradle sync and invalidating the cache. Nothing worked. The font is preloaded, the file exists. The folder is accessible. The files are not corrupted or anything. I've even deleted the font files and redownloaded them via Android Studio Design view.

Comment: Please Try to delete .xml file.

Comment: As I said, I've tried deleting the fonts and reading them one by one. Even deleting preloaded_fonts.xml.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and it seems that it's caused by using a custom font-family. When I change @font/our_font_family by @our_font it works.

Comment: Yes, removing custom font families works, but I need them in my app, so this is not an options.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with custom font-families on Dolphin, Electric Eel and Flamingo.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue has been partially fixed on Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1. You have to delete the font folder and redownload the font.

The easiest way is to go to a layout file, go to Design, select a text box and in the fontFamily attribute, select More Fonts. Search for the font family you wish and install all missing fonts.

Refresh the layout by clicking the "Try to refresh the layout" option if it does not load by itself.

Comment: That's weird that fonts already present are not compatible for new android studio version, but somehow this trick worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

From the history at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/248473636, it appears that this issue has been addressed in Electric Eel Beta 4 and Flamingo Canary 7.

Comment: ymmv, however. This fix apparently does not address the issue for me.

Comment: Let's see how it behaves once it gets released.

Comment: It did address my issue when finally released.

Answer (score 1):

Check inside `rubik_bold.xml` if you have a valid font defined in the `android:font` tag and also make sure that you are not accessing the same file in that tag `(eg android:font=@font/rubik_bold)`.

Answer (score -2):

I have found a work around this, android studio is not recognising fonts(some with medium, bold forexample rubik_medium), please remove those fonts and the preview will work utilize the error warning in the top corner of preview window. i have found non xml fonts working seemlessly eg. .ttf fonts

Comment: As I said before in the comments, removing the fonts is not a real sollution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).